# Adding an hyperlink to text using python-pptx

Tags: python, python-pptx

I am trying to add an external hyperlink to text in my slide using the python-pptx module. For some reason, I can't figure out how to do it. Following the examples I could find online, it should as simple as `shape.click_action.hyperlink.address = "URL"` but it does not work in my case. I don't know if I am missing something or if this is just not possible, I am very new with this module, and it seems quite complicated.

Here is my code:

```
from pptx import Presentation

prs = Presentation()

slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[0]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(slide_layout)

title = slide.shapes[0]
title.text = "My title"
title.click_action.hyperlink.address = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
```